# How do I create a tuple of N T's from an array of T?

Tags: c++, arrays, tuples, c++14

If I have a `constexpr` array of `N` integers, how do I convert it to an appropriate `constexpr std::tuple<...>`?

Comment: Is your array a raw array or a `std::array` or what?

Comment: Why would you want a `tuple` when you already have an array?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is a possible implementation for raw arrays:

```
#include<functional>

template<std::size_t... I, std::size_t N>
constexpr auto f(const int (&arr)[N], std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    return std::make_tuple(arr[I]...);
}

template<std::size_t N>
constexpr auto f(const int (&arr)[N]) {
    return f(arr, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}

int main() {
    constexpr int arr[] = { 0, 1, 2 };
    constexpr auto tup = f(arr);
    static_assert(std::get<0>(tup) == 0, "!");
    static_assert(std::get<1>(tup) == 1, "!");
    static_assert(std::get<2>(tup) == 2, "!");
}
```

The size of a `constexpr` array can be deduced at compile-time, so you don't have to explicitly specify it.
That size can be used internally to create a set of indices to get the elements out from the array and create the tuple on the fly.

---

As mentioned in the comments, if you want to generalize a bit more and accept both raw arrays and `std::array`s, you can do this:

```
#include<functional>
#include<array>

template<std::size_t... I, typename U>
constexpr auto f(const U &arr, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    return std::make_tuple(arr[I]...);
}

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr auto f(const T (&arr)[N]) {
    return f(arr, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr auto f(const std::array<T, N> &arr) {
    return f(arr, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}

int main() {
    constexpr int arr1[] = { 0, 1, 2 };
    constexpr auto tup1 = f(arr1);
    static_assert(std::get<0>(tup1) == 0, "!");
    static_assert(std::get<1>(tup1) == 1, "!");
    static_assert(std::get<2>(tup1) == 2, "!");

    constexpr std::array<int, 3> arr2 = { 0, 1, 2 };
    constexpr auto tup2 = f(arr2);
    static_assert(std::get<0>(tup2) == 0, "!");
    static_assert(std::get<1>(tup2) == 1, "!");
    static_assert(std::get<2>(tup2) == 2, "!");
}
```

Comment: I like this answer, it has a cleaner/slimmer interface. Thanks!

Comment: I combined your answer with my own to cover both basic array's and std::array<T, N>

Comment: @Short I wouldn't do as you did for `std::array` though. If you want, I can update my answer to cover them too.

Comment: thanks, i was able to make mine much cleaner now based off that.

Comment: @Short Why are you copying another answer to integrate your? This doesn't make much sense. They do not have to be identical.

Answer (score 2):

Converting an array into a tuple takes advantage of [std::integer sequence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence), building up the array indices at compile time as the compiler invokes the helper function for 0..N.

Here's the code which demonstrates this.
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b2d6c6ca1f5dc635

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// tuple_from_array
namespace detail {
template<typename T, std::size_t... Is>
auto constexpr tuple_from_array(T const& arr, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
  return std::make_tuple(arr[Is]...);
}

template<std::size_t N, typename V, typename T, std::size_t ...Is>
auto constexpr array_from_container(T const& c, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
  return std::array<V, N>{c[Is]...};
}

} // ns detail

template<typename T>
auto constexpr tuple_from_array(T const& arr)
{
  auto constexpr tup_size = std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<T>>::value;
  return detail::tuple_from_array(arr, std::make_index_sequence<tup_size>{});
}

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
auto constexpr tuple_from_array(T const (&arr)[N])
{
  return detail::tuple_from_array(arr, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}

// not safe
template<std::size_t N, typename T>
auto constexpr tuple_from_container(T const& c)
{
  using V = typename T::value_type;
  return tuple_from_array(detail::array_from_container<N, V>(c, std::make_index_sequence<N>{}));
}
```

edit: I combined skypjack@'s answer with my own to cover basic arrays as queried in the comments. I can't re-put this as my own answer for two days though :(

Comment: Posting a helpful Q&A is always encouraged. But a "code-dump" answer isn't the epitome of quality. I suggest you edit it with an explanation.

Comment: How does this have "zero overhead at runtime"?

Comment: The constexpr functions convert the array to a tuple at compile time. Sorry, I updated the example and code link to instantiate the tuple as a constexpr value.

Comment: Exposing an internal detail as a template parameter to the user isn't good practice: if the parameter exists, users *will* start using and abusing it. It's also unnecessary here, since you can just use `index_sequence_for` instead.

Comment: @StoryTeller your right, I updated my answer with more details about the std::integer_sequence expansion.

Comment: What's the point of the `decay_t` applied to the array type T? Doesn't that reduce it to a pointer to item type? How can that then tell you array size? OH, the T type is a `std::array`. How about raw array then?

Comment: @KerrekSB I'm unsure hw to make those edits. My attempts end in compilation failure, though I do see your point. The example usages I've found invoke index_sequence_for on a parameter pack. I don't have a parameter pack here, I'm unsure at the moment how to make your change.

Comment: @Short: I'm sorry, `index_sequence_for` isn't useful here. But you should stick the size computation directly into the call site regardless and not make a public template parameter out of it. (You could use an intermediate private  template, if you like, but that doesn't seem necessary.)

Comment: @KerrekSB your suggestion made me think, it's super obvious just to use a using statement. Updated, thanks!